# How to make a graph from the produced in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, graph, networkx

I have this code, it produces a random matrix of 1s and 0s. I want to create a graph from this matrix where the 1s in the matrix represent a node and each node has a maximum of 3 edges. How can i implement this, please help?

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

N = int(input("Enter the number of nodes:"))
my_matrix = np.zeros((N,N), dtype='int8')
```

Comment: Is matrix `my_matrix` - [adjacency matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacencyMatrix.html)?

Comment: yes it is an adjacency matrix. I also want to take input from the user on how any edges he/she wants to be connected to all the nodes. For eg: if the user inputs 2, i want the each node to be having maximum of 2 edges from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you matrix is just random, probably, you don't need it. Instead, you can create graph from list of edges

```
import networkx as nx
from random import sample
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint


n = 7  # number of nodes in graph
max_connections = int(input("Enter max connections per node:"))  # input: 3

nodes = np.arange(n)
# create graph based on list of edges [(0, 1), (0, 4), ...]
gr = nx.Graph([
    #     for each node      select <= 'max_connections' nodes as connections
    (i, j) for i in range(n) for j in sample(nodes[nodes != i].tolist(), randint(1, max_connections+1))
])

# check number of connections
for n in gr.nodes():
    nei = list(gr.neighbors(n))
    while len(nei) > max_connections:
        gr.remove_edge(n, random.choice(nei))
        nei = list(gr.neighbors(n))

nx.draw_networkx(gr, with_labels=True, node_color='#7d99f5')
```

Graph:
[image]

And you can get adjacency matrix using `nx.adjacency_matrix()`

```
nx.adjacency_matrix(gr, nodelist=sorted(gr.nodes())).todense()

matrix([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: All the nodes in the output do not quite follow the max connections rule. Many nodes are exceeding the limit

Comment: Yep, I see. I added loop to check number of connections

Comment: Yepp it works perfectly now, thank you! But I want to use a randomly generated matrix for which i had the code above and on basis of the positions of '1s' in the matrix I want a node on exactly that position in a grid. How can I implement that?

Comment: Okay, if you want to use **exactly** your matrix, just put matrix in function `gr = nx.from_numpy_matrix(my_matrix)`

Comment: But your algorithm does not prevent from 1) self loops 2) exceeding limit of edges per node. I will probably fix it soon

Comment: What is the MAX number of nodes your graph can have?

Comment: yes exactly, i tried it too, it doesnt fix self looping and limiting edges. The max number of nodes is not defined, i want it to depend on the user but i can say the max number of nodes will never exceed 50 or even 40 is fine. Thank you!

Comment: I have added another sol-n.

Answer (score 1):

**complete update :**

- if bi-directional is not important, then the adjM is tri-diagonal
- if not more than 3 edges per node are allowed, then each row and each column of adjM has 3 or less "1"
- the code follows the tri-diagnoal structure required
- *step 1*: fill in 3 edges starting from each node (follow the rows of adjM)
- *step 2*: but then some nodes may receive more than 3 edges, so remove some of them until there are 3 left only (follow the columnes of adjM)
- *step 3*: remove the self-adjacencies
- yes, it might happen that the graph will not be connected due to the random processes. Then repeat the runs till you are happy with.

The structure of adjM looks reasonable now at least. The graph however presents at node 12 more connections than can be seen in the adjM matrix. (so there is still an improvement necessary....)

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Nnodes = 16
Nedges = 3

#---- 0. to initialize: generate a random adjacency matrix 
rng = np.random.default_rng()
adjM = rng.integers(1, size=(Nnodes,Nnodes))  # random adjacency matrix / with upper=1 it is a zero matrix


#---- 1. for eaach node generate randomly Nedges edges ("sending" connections alongs the rows of adjM)
for node in range(Nnodes):
    dd = Nnodes-node
    rand_ind = np.random.choice(np.arange(node,Nnodes), size=min(dd,Nedges), replace=False, p=None) # generate randomly indexes
                                                                                       # you might use replace=False too with different results
    adjM[node, rand_ind] = 1   # insert the connections        

#---- 2. for each node eliminate randomly edges that are more than Nedges ("receiving" connections alongs the columns of adjM)
for node in range(Nnodes):          # run through the columns of adjM
    dd = Nnodes-node
    a = adjM[:,node]                # select a column = receiving connections
    jnz = np.array(a.nonzero())     # indices of the non-zero elements
    Nnz = jnz.shape[1]              # number of  non-zero elements
    
    if Nnz > Nedges:                # ...then randomly select Nedges edges only 
        jchoice = np.random.choice(jnz.ravel(),  size=min(Nedges,Nedges), replace=False, p=None)
        #print('            jchoice', jchoice)
        adjM[:,node] = 0
        adjM[jchoice, node] = 1           
        
 #---- 3. remove self-adjacency
jDiag = np.arange(Nnodes)
adjM[jDiag, jDiag] = 0         # set the diagonals to zero
print(adjM) 
        
#---- grafics
plt.spy(adjM, precision=0, marker=None, markersize=12, aspect='equal', origin='upper')
plt.show()
gr = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjM)
nx.draw_networkx(gr, with_labels=True, node_size=400, node_color='#7d99f5',  edge_color='orange', width=2, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Addition to your code (function `check_graph ()` fix two problems we have discussed). Also, according your way of generation of adjacency matrix, you won't face second problem, so you can comment out second section in function.

```
def check_graph(graph, max_conn):
    # 1) remove self loops
    graph.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(graph))

    # 2) remove random edge(s) if limit of edges per node have been exceeded
    for i in graph.nodes():
        # list of connections - nodes that are connected to the selected node 'i'
        nei = list(graph.neighbors(i))
        if len(nei) > max_conn:
            graph.remove_edges_from(
                # like if len(nei) - max_conn = 5 - 4 = 1, then one random edge will be selected
                np.random.choice(nei, size=(len(nei)-max_conn))
            )

# <-- insert your code here -->  N = 20

gr = nx.from_numpy_matrix(my_matrix)
check_graph(gr, max_conn=N)
nx.draw_networkx(gr, with_labels=True, node_color='#7d99f5')
```

Result looks a bit strange for me, but I don't know purposes of your graph, probably, it's okay.

[image]

Comment: No sorry actually this is not what I wanted. The solution you sent above is very close to how I want i will try to work forward on that. And it's fine, i can work with that too. Thank you so much for your time and help really appreciate it brother!

Comment: Btw Network lib has a lot of built-in [graph generators](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.classic) (like `gnp_random_graph`), maybe one of them will fit your purposes)